# PostgreSQL loading a module without shared_preload_libraries

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing an extension for PostgreSQL in C language.
The extension is loaded by PostgreSQL when I specify its' name in shared_preload_libraries.
Out of curiosity, is there a way for PG to load my extension without specifying its' name in shared_preload_libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load extension modules:

- From [`shared_preload_libraries`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html). This loads at postmaster start time, so the extension can register shared memory, locks, hooks etc before we start forking backends.
- With `session_preload_libraries`. This loads after fork(), in a backend, so it can't register shmem etc.
- With `local_preload_libraries`. Like `session_preload_libraries`, but limited to the `plugins` directory and settable by normal users.
- With the `LOAD` statement, or implicitly by running a function that refers to a `LANGUAGE c` implementation.

There's no alternative to getting the full effect of `shared_preload_libraries`. The other options don't permit you to do things that require code to be run in the postmaster, like register addin LWLocks or static shared memory segments. But if you don't do those things a simple `LOAD` suffices.